# What might be the reason for licence compliance violation?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

Much to my surprise we got a licence compliance violation for our DB2 Workgroup Server Edition installation regarding:

```
~]$ db2licm -g tmp.txt
~]$ cat tmp.txt

 License Compliance Report
 DB2 Workgroup Server Edition   Violation
    Materialized Query Tables
    Multidimensional Clustering Tables
```

Since we are not using any of these I was kind of puzzled, how can this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause might be that someone created a sample database using db2sampl. The sample database contains both of these artefacts:

```
]$ db2 -x "select tabschema, tabname, type, clustered 
           from syscat.tables 
           where type = 'S' or clustered = 'Y'"

DB2INST1    ADEFUSR    S    -        
DB2INST1    EMPMDC     T    Y
```

It appears as if something in the instance is flipped during create of sample database, dropping the sample database does not help, the violation persists.

As @Chris Aldrich points out in the comment, `db2licm -x` does a reset of the license report:

```
DB2 Workgroup Server Edition   In compliance
```

Out of curiosity I created 1 MQT to see if the violation re-appears. So far it has not. It's now more than 12 hours since I created the MQT and I'm still in compliance.

I'm still puzzled by how the licence compliance mechanism works, but I'll add another question about that.

Comment: If you have removed the offending items, you could try db2licm -x to reset the license report. I have had mixed success with that in the past. Not sure if it requires instance bounce? But it supposedly clears the license report so you can generate it clean.